# How to protect ConnectionStrings in Azure IoT Edge module code?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Typing the connection string in the configuration file (as shown in the official example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-samples/blob/master/js/simple/gw.cloud.config.json#L38) doesn't seem right.

Environment variables may be provided to the modules by the Edge Runtime (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime.md) but as far as I can see there is no way to modify its behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first document(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-edge-samples/blob/master/js/simple/gw.cloud.config.json#L38), it shows how to customize the IoT Edge runtime (gw.[local|cloud].config.json). You can update `gw.cloud.config.json` by replacing `<IoT Hub device connection string>` with your actual IoT Hub device connection string to establish connection between IoT Edge application and Azure IoT Hub.

In the next document(https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime.md), you can also configure the IoT Edge runtime by executing the following command.You will find the connection string setting in `C:\ProgramData\azure-iot-edge\config\config.json`.

> iotedgectl setup --connection-string "{device connection string}" --nopass

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but: isn't `gw.cloud.config.json` part of the source code of the project that is going to be deployed in the device? If I store my credentials there then I'm actually embedding the connection string in the code files.

Probably the point is I'm not using the Edge Hub (I actually wasn't aware of its existance) and I inferred from the source code of the sample the module should communicate directly with the Azure Iot Hub.

I didn't find any reference to iotedgectl setup in the second link you provided but I think I can manage myself from there. Thanks, Michael!

Comment: Well, you pointed me in the right direction: the IoT Edge runtime container exposes the connection string of the device through the `DeviceConnectionString` env variable. I just need to use it in the module code.